# How exactly does a unique asset get tokenized?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens

Say I have a set of assets, each with their own serial# or unique Id. How exactly would I create tokens linked to each asset that could be traded on a 1 to many basis? (ie: trade this one special token for multiple ether)

After looking at some solidity contract code I see many examples of how to create a batch of tokens out of nothing, but I do not see (or understand) how to assign unique values or embed data into a single token.

I hear a lot about how blockchain can be used for this type of thing but it isn't apparent exactly how that is possible.

Comment: If you could provide an example from real world, it would be easier to respond.

Comment: A limited edition print or basically any item with a unique identifying number attached to the physical asset. How does the physical asset get linked to a virtual token?